# Save e-mail in legacy database through Keycloak SPI

Tags: java, keycloak

I've created a **Keycloak SPI** in order to allow authentication through Keycloak 9.0.0 using a legacy database schema (Oracle).

Basically, I implemented the interface [org.keycloak.storage.user.UserRegistrationProvider](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/server-spi/src/main/java/org/keycloak/storage/user/UserRegistrationProvider.java) **to insert** and **remove** the user into/from the database table. My question is: How can I save the e-mail  (and first name and last name fields) if the method in the interface receives only the username?

```java
public interface UserRegistrationProvider {

 UserModel addUser(RealmModel realm, String username);

}

public class MyUserStorageProvider implements UserRegistrationProvider, ... {

  @Override
  public UserModel addUser(final RealmModel realm, final String username) {
    // TODO INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (name) VALUES (?);
    // TODO And the e-mail field?
  }

}
```

[image: Adding user]

Is there another Java interface that I have to implement to save these information?

Comment: Looking for the same functionality. Did you get anything ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have just debugged it: KeyCloak will call the setters on the UserModel implementation (some kind of UserAdapter) you return from the addUser method, after addUser has been executed.
As far as I know, no other SPI method gets called, so you need to trigger the save in the setters themselves. This also holds true when you edit the user in the KeyCloak console.

Comment: Btw.: The KeyCloak preferred way to do the actual save is at the end of the update transaction. If you return an attached entity, KeyCloak calls the setters, and at commit time the data should be saved successfully. See [link](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-4323)